# How to fix 'selected node' hiding issue while treeview is disabled?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, .net-4.7

I am using the treeview control in my windows form application and in my functionality treeview needs to be disabled but problem was that after disabling my treeview's selected node is not display It was hide.

I tried also EnsureVisible property before disabling treeview but also selected node was hide after disabling treeview.

treeview1.SelectedNode.EnsureVisible();
treeview1.Enabled = false;

I expect that after disabling selected node of treeview will not hide anyway.

[here selected node is first node which name is Desktop It is not displaying after disabling treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVVzN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution.

I set Forecolor of selected node and then disable treeview so when treeview was disable selected node is not hiding.

```
treeview1.SelectedNode.ForeColor=Colors.Black;
treeview1.Enabled=False;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw your TreeView by yourself and set it's OwnerDraw to true or as an easy solution you can just set a bool value to false and whenever you want to hide set this value to false then return on treeview events so nothing will change on your UI

Comment: There is no OwnerDraw property for treeview.

Comment: Then you can do the second option. Bind it to a bool value and return what you do on your events based on its value